# Spliting out tuples from a line in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file the looks something like this:

```
abs=1 sin=2.1 cat=curve line=3
abs=2 sin=3.4 cat=sawtooth line=8
abs=7 sin=6.3 cat=square line=4
```

In reality, I have several more fields and not all lines have all fields.  Anyway, I want to write a script where the user can define a "mask" of the tuples they want to keep (eg abs,line) and then the script outputs a smaller version of the file with only values in the given fields.

For example, I give the script an input parameter "abs,line", it prints this:

```
abs=1 line=3
abs=2 line=8
abs=7 line=4
```

I'm doing several things like this in bash and would like to integrate into my bash script.  I'm thinking awk must be able to do this, but I can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to pad the mask as suggested by *glenn* in the comments, this makes the matching more robust:

```
mask=abs,line
awk -v mask=$mask -v RS='[\n ]' -v FS='=' -v ORS='' '
  BEGIN { mask="," mask "," }
  mask ~ "," $1 "," { print $1 FS $2 RT }
'
```

Note, set the `mask` variable to a comma separated list of the parameters you want to extract.

Records are separated by newlines or space, and are reinserted at the end with `RT`.

Output:

```
abs=1 line=3
abs=2 line=8
abs=7 line=4
```

Comment: This sounds like a promising solution.  However, I intend to give the user `n` number of fields to extract.  If I made the script say something like `print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 RT`, would it work if I had any number of parameters in my mask less than or equal to five?  Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Thor, that's the approach I'd take as well. I would make the matching more robust by adding anchors: `awk ... 'BEGIN {mask = "," mask ","} mask ~ "," $1 "," {...}'`

Comment: @User1, you'll need to be more specific -- what exactly does the "mask" look like?

Comment: @glenn, The mask might be two parameters (eg abs,line), but could be any number of parameters (abs) or (abs,line,cat) or (abs,line,cat,sin).

Comment: @User1, then Thor's answer still works. Just pass the variable containing the mask to awk with `awk -v mask="$mask" ...`

Comment: @glenn: good idea about padding the mask with commas, I'll add it to the answer. @user1: this solution uses space and newline as separator, so it matches each parameter with value individually, i.e. we only have to deal with `$1` and `$2` at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make `abs` and `line` separate parameters, rather than a single comma-separated one, making the script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A keep;

# read variables to keep from command line into associative array
while (( $# )); do
  keep[$1]=1
  shift
done

# process input
while read -r; do
  read -a args <<<"$REPLY"
  for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    key=${arg%=*}
    value=${arg#*=}
    if [[ ${keep[$key]} ]] ; then
      printf '%s=%s ' "$key" "$value"
    fi
  done
  printf '\n'
done
```

Then run the script as follows:

```
./yourscript abs line <input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach using `awk`:

Assuming `infile` with the content pasted in the question, create the mask and execute following script:

```
m="abs,line,cat"; awk -v mask="$m" '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = " ";

        ## Set fields of the mask as keys of an array.
        ret = split( mask, arr, /,/ );
        for ( i = 1; i <= length( arr ); i++ ) {
            mask_arr[ arr[i] ] = 1;
        }
    }

    ## Go throught all fields, extract the first part until the equal sign,
    ## search it in the array and print if found.
    {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
            if ( substr( $i, 1, index( $i, "=" ) - 1 ) in mask_arr ) {
                printf "%s%s", $i, OFS;
            }
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
' infile
```

With the result of:

```
abs=1 cat=curve line=3 
abs=2 cat=sawtooth line=8 
abs=7 cat=square line=4
```